# Not getting selected value from drop down box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having an issue getting the correct value from my drop down box.  Basically what I have is a program with a drop down list that is populated with names that are saved in a database table.  The user selects a name from the drop down box and then clicks a button to remove the name from the database.  The issue I am having is that no matter which name is selected, the first name (with an index of 0) is deleted from the drop down box.

This leads me to believe that the SelectedIndex is reset when the button is clicked, which I don't understand.

Code of delete button:

```
protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=myname-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbNames;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Names WHERE FirstName=@FirstName AND LastName=@LastName", conn);
            char[] delims = new char[1];
            delims[0] = ' ';

            //lblGreeting.Text = cblNames.

            lblGreeting.Text = ddlNames.SelectedItem.Text;
            string[] names = ddlNames.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(delims);
            string fname = names[0];
            string lname = names[1];
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", fname));
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", lname));
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            LoadTable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Delete Table: "+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

I'm not really sure what should change if the page is not being rendered for the first time or why that would change what I want that function to do.  It is being called after the button is clicked, and the value should be taken before the table is rendered again.  I'll include LoadTable() in case it helps:

```
protected void LoadTable() 
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=myname-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbNames;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Names",conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader rd = comm.ExecuteReader();
                string fname="";
                string lname="";
                ddlNames.Items.Clear();
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    fname = rd.GetString(0);
                    lname = rd.GetString(1);
                    ddlNames.Items.Add(fname + " " + lname);
                }
                rd.Close();
            }                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Load Table: "+ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Two other functions:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadTable();

}

protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=myname-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbNames;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            char[] splits = new char[1];
            splits[0] = ' ';
            string fname = txtName.Text.Split(splits)[0];
            string lname = txtName.Text.Split(splits)[1];
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Names VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName)",conn);
            comm.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", fname);
            comm.Parameters.Add("@LastName", lname);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            LoadTable();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Add Name: "+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the only code in the Page_Load() function

Comment: can you post the page_load function, please?

Comment: I've included the rest of the code.  The Add_Click is pretty irrelevant as far as I can imagine

Comment: Have you ever set any break point in the delete event and debugged it?

Comment: Can you change the page_load function as the way in my answer and try it?

Comment: @stmnnmn I'm not sure what you mean by the "master page" I'm relatively new to C#

Comment: @KirinYao It's not the delete button that I'm having issues with.  It deletes just fine.   The problem is when I try to select a name it seems as if the drop down box refreshes and it always goes back to the index with a value of 0.

Comment: @daryal Do you really want me to add that in Page_Load and enter them again manually?  I would be including all of the same code to populate the drop down box as I did in the LoadTable function.  I don't see what the difference would be.

Comment: I have updated the answer before my comment, if you want to get an answer, please respect the people trying to help you, at least read what they have written.

Comment: @daryal I apologize.  The page automatically included your comment but I hadn't refreshed my page to see your edit.  I sincerely apologize for the misunderstanding.  That did work but I don't understand quite why.  Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: yes offcourse it would happen if you dont put the if(!ispostback) on page load..@daryal is right..try it first.. becoz every time the page load method is called when any server side control event is fired. like in your case button click..

Comment: @m.webster no problem, page_load function is called every time you do a postback, like clicking a button. It means everytime you click a button, your data is populated again and your selection is lost. You may debug it, put a breakpoint into page_load function and observe the behaviour when you click a button. Page.IsPostBack checks whether page is loaded as a submit from the form itself; since first call to page is from another page, the property is false. then, inside the page when you do a submit action, this property is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are possibly populating the dropdown in the Page_Load function and you do not have a Page.IsPostBack check. Thus everytime the list is populated again. Change the population code to something like:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadTable();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ddlNames.SelectedItem.Value instead.